# How to detect when UIImageView flip vertically

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I check from UIImageView's scaleY but it doesn't work (see the code below).

```
CGAffineTransform t = [myImageView transform]; // Keep matrix value of UIImageView
float scaleY1 = sqrt(t.b * t.b + t.d * t.d);   // 1.0000
CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformScale(t, 1, -1.0); // flip UIImageView vertically
float scaleY2 = sqrt(t2.b * t2.b + t2.d * t2.d); // 1.0000
[myImageView setTransform:t2];
NSLog(@"1: %f, 2: %f", scaleY1, scaleY2); // 1: 1.0000, 2: 1.0000
```

From above, you can see that before and after we flip the UIImageView, we got the same "scaleY value".

What is the value that we should check? (in order to detect when UIImageView flip vertically)

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the transform property of the imageview? You will see there if the view has been transformed. This is what I see if I print the value of myImageView in console after aplying the transformation:

> (lldb) po myImageView
>
> UIImageView: 0x8f59f30; frame = (0 0; 0 0); transform = [1, 0, -0,
>   -1, 0, 0]; userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but could you please give me more information about which value in matrix that I should check in order to know that UIImageView is flipping right now. I know that this property has minus value, which means it is flipping, but I am not sure that when I rotate UIImageView -> I don't know which value in the matrix will tell me exactly that UIImageView is flipping right now?

Comment: Try different values and see how that matrix changes, and here you can find what it means https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGAffineTransform

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[UIView transitionWithView: flipTile
                  duration: 0.5
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    flipTile.image = newTileImage;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    /*
                        code after completion
                    */
                }
 ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but in my case, I will get one image from somewhere, and I want to detect that it's flip or not?

Comment: wherever your image is flipped in complition use nsnotification to notify the flip of the image

Comment: In my case, it's not about animation. but anyway thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of jay gajjar is fine.

But if you dont want to animate then use

```
[UIView transitionWithView: flipTile
                  duration: 0.0
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    flipTile.image = newTileImage;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    /*
                        code after completion
                    */
                }
 ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but in my case, I will get one image from somewhere, and I want to detect that it's flip or not?