# How to detect CGAffineTransform is flipped?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cgaffinetransform

I want to know the way to detect a transform of view is flipped or not.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855422/how-to-detect-when-uiimageview-flip-vertically) but there is no answer I expected.

And also tried to detect using with a 3 by 3 matrix of [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGAffineTransform).
But I'm not good at math and this kind of matrix....

So Cloud anyone please help me...

Answer (score 1):

**CGAffineTransform** has properties to detect that,

Like I say,

`aTransformObj.a` : represents   `scale X`

`aTransformObj.b` : represents   `skew  Y`

`aTransformObj.c` : represents   `skew  X`

`aTransformObj.d` : represents   `scale Y`

`aTransformObj.tx` : represents   `translate x`

`aTransformObj.ty` : represents   `translate Y`

You can check with if those values are negative or not,
1) `.a` property value if it is `more then 0 to any negative value` then it is horizontally flipped.
2) `.d` property value if it is `more then 0 to any negative value` then it is vertically flipped.

Comment: That's not true. the `d` component is simply the [2,2] of the matrix. This is -1 for a rotation of 180, too. Moreover, if you have a flip and a zoom, .d is not -1, but another negative value. As mentioned in my answer, this assumption is only correct, if you do not have further transformations.

Comment: but we can check with negative value! if the value is negative then it is flipped! doesn't seems right to you?

Comment: I do not think so, because this can still be a rotation or an panning. I do not think, that you can check for a single transformation in a chain of transformations. This only works, if you have a single flip transformation.

Answer (score 0):

A transformation is not flipped. A view is flipped. To do so, a transformation is applied. So the transformation flips the view, it is not flipped itself.

So you can read the transformation of a view and check, whether it is the flip transformation. (A scale transformation with a scaling factor of 1 for the x-axis and -1 for the y-axis.) But it is possible that many transformations are applied to the  view. So maybe, you do not get the "pure" flip transformation. And at the end of the day, it depends on what you call "flipped". Is a rotation of 180° a flip? (What is your real problem?)

However, the most robust way to check that seems to get the transformation and transform a point. The result gives you a hint, what is done. If the sign of the y coordinate changes, but the value of the x-coordinate remains constant, it looks like a flip. (On the first view.)